# one question about differential geometry,show the curvature k($\phi$)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

One often gives a plane curve in polar coordinates by $p=p(\phi)$,$a\le\phi \le b$.
(1)Show that the arc length is $$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{p^2+\dot p^2}$$,where $\dot p$ means the derivative of p with respect to $\phi$.

(2) show that the curvature is $$k(\phi)={{2\dot p^2-p\ddot p+p^2}\over ({\dot p^2+p^2})^{3\over 2}}$$

This problem is from my textbook, I have finished the first question, but when I tried to finish the second question, I tried to compute $d^2\alpha(s)\over ds^2$, I got a huge and complicated derivative. I am stuck here, can someone tell me me how to finish the second question, I think my method is not good. Can someone tell me how to solve the second problem? thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the paragraph "Local Expressions" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: Oh, maybe I need to use  $d\theta(S) \over ds $ to compute